# When calling printf multiple times, only the first printf works

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, att

This is the code that I am using:

```
printing:
    decq    %r13
    movq    $0, %rax
    movq    %r8, %rsi
    movq    $output, %rdi
    call     printf
    cmpq    $0, %r13
    jg    printing
```

where `%r13` is used as the counter.

So as I saw while debugging in GDB, if I have a value of 5 in `%r13`, the subroutine `printing` does get executed 5 times, 1 after another. But for some reason, I never get the value that is in `%r8` printed more than once. No matter if the number in `%r13` is 1 or 50.

And if I change the value of `%r8` or `%rsi`, then that value also gets printed only once.

What could be causing printf just not to print the contents of `%r8` more than one time?

Comment: Please post your complete code or a [mcve].  Also please let us know what operating system you are programming for.

Comment: `r8` is call-clobbered, so later executions of `movq    %r8, %rsi` will pass some garbage value.